# I want to broadcast to different client

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, websocket

So this code broadcasts to all the clients connected to it (including itself) but rather I want to broadcast to a specific client. How do I do that?

```
import socket, threading                                                #Libraries import

host = '127.0.0.1'                                                      #LocalHost
port = 7978                                                            #Choosing unreserved port

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)              #socket initialization
server.bind((host, port))                                               #binding host and port to socket
server.listen()

clients = []
nicknames = []

def broadcast(message):                                                 #broadcast function declaration
    for client in clients:
        print(client, type(client))
        client.send(message)

def handle(client):                                         
    while True:
        try:                                                            #recieving valid messages from client
            message = client.recv(1024)
            broadcast(message)
        except:                                                         #removing clients
            index = clients.index(client)
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()
            nickname = nicknames[index]
            broadcast('{} left!'.format(nickname).encode('ascii'))
            nicknames.remove(nickname)
            break

def receive():                                                          #accepting multiple clients
    
    while True:
        client, address = server.accept()
        print("Connected with {}".format(str(address)))       
        client.send('NICKNAME'.encode('ascii'))
        nickname = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
        nicknames.append(nickname)
        clients.append(client)
        print("Nickname is {}".format(nickname))
        broadcast("{} joined!".format(nickname).encode('ascii'))
        client.send('Connected to server!'.encode('ascii'))
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(client,))
        thread.start()
        
receive()
```

If a client sends message the server will broadcast the message to all clients including the client that sent the message. Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: If you don't want to send a message to a client, then don't call client.send(message)

Comment: I want to send the message just to the other client not the client that is sending the message.

Comment: So don't call the send function of that client

Comment: In terms of code how do I do that?

Comment: you send a message to all the clients except that one

Comment: By changing the handle and broadcast function?

Comment: You could make a "send to all clients except this one" function, whose parameters are the message, and which client NOT to send it to.

Comment: ```
def broadcast(message, client):                                                 
    if clients(0) == client:
        client.send(message)
    else:
        client.send(message)
```
Is this correct?

Comment: What does that code tell the computer to do? Explain to me in English, to test your understanding.

Comment: everytime I recieve a message from a client I send the message along with client info to the broadcast function. In the broadcast function I'm checking if its same client, if so don't send else send.

Comment: No. Read what you wrote. You wrote a function that sends the message to the client if it is the first client, otherwise it sends the message to the client. Is that sensible? You tell me.

Comment: def broadcast(message, clientt):                                                
    for client in clients:
        if client == clientt:
            continue
        else:
            clientt.send(message)
Is this any better?

Comment: that almost does what you want, but not quite

Comment: Honestly I don't know how to proceed. Can you tell me please?

Comment: you could try using your last code and see what's wrong with it, then fix that.

Comment: Now the client is talking to itself.

Comment: have a careful look at the broadcast function you wrote and you should be able to figure out why the client is talking to itself

Comment: Yup got it. Its fixed now! 
Thanks

Comment: Now that you have answered your own question you can write an answer :) although it probably will not be useful to anyone except you, because the problem is very specific to your code

Comment: Yup your right!

Answer (score 0):

Change broadcast function to the following:

```
import socket, threading                                                #Libraries import

host = '127.0.0.1'                                                      #LocalHost
port = 7978                                                            #Choosing unreserved port

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)              #socket initialization
server.bind((host, port))                                               #binding host and port to socket
server.listen()

clients = []
nicknames = []

def broadcast(message, clientt):                                                 #broadcast function declaration
    for client in clients:
        if client == clientt:
            continue
        else:
            client.send(message)
    # for client in clients:
    #     print(client, type(client))
    #     client.send(message)

def handle(client):                                         
    while True:
        try:                                                            #recieving valid messages from client
            message = client.recv(1024)
            broadcast(message, client)
        except:                                                         #removing clients
            index = clients.index(client)
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()
            nickname = nicknames[index]
            broadcast('{} left!'.format(nickname).encode('ascii'), client)
            nicknames.remove(nickname)
            break

def receive():                                                          #accepting multiple clients
    
    while True:
        client, address = server.accept()
        print("Connected with {}".format(str(address)))       
        client.send('NICKNAME'.encode('ascii'))
        nickname = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
        nicknames.append(nickname)
        clients.append(client)
        print("Nickname is {}".format(nickname))
        broadcast("{} joined!".format(nickname).encode('ascii'), client)
        client.send('Connected to server!'.encode('ascii'))
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(client,))
        thread.start()
        
receive()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).